# Is it possible to have \listoffigures and \begin{bibliography} on the same page?

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

I'm trying to have the \listoffigures and the bibliography on the same page.

I'm using the following commands:

```
\documentclass [a4paper,11pt,oneside]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=3.5cm,bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{figure} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{scrpage2} 
\usepackage{nameref} 
\usepackage{gensymb} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\clearscrheadings
\clearscrplain
\clearscrheadfoot

\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}

\ihead{\headmark}  

\setheadsepline{0,4pt} 
\setfootsepline{0,4pt}  
\rofoot{Seite \thepage\ von 11}
\lofoot{Protokoll: ...,...}

\setheadwidth{text}
\setfootwidth{text}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\parindent 0pt 
\parskip 0pt

\title{\textbf{Protokoll: Versuch 10/1 - Dünne Linsen}\vspace*{20mm}}
%
\author{\rmfamily von \textbf{...} und \textbf{...}\\
\\\textbf{\rmfamily Assistent:}\rmfamily\ ...} 
%
%
\date{\textbf{\rmfamily Datum:}\rmfamily\ 26. Mai 2014 - 02. Juni 2014}



\begin{document}
```

...

```
\listoffigures
% % %
\begin{bibliography}{9}

%

\bibitem{name}

   Prof. ...
   Filename...
   Date...

%

\bibitem{name2}

   Prof. ...
   Filename2
   Date2
```

...
and so on...

Now, the command above gives me both. The listoffigures und the bibliography but each on a different page.

I'd like them to be both on the same page.

Is this possible?

Thanks

EDIT: for documentclass

Comment: Can you please edit your post and include a complete compilable code. Most important is the document class as some modify the default behaviour of standard classes. So for now, I can only answer: Yes, it is possible to do that.

Comment: So, edited it. Could've thought of that- sry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
foo

\begin{figure}\centering
foo
\caption{bar}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures
\begingroup
\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem[foo] bar baz
\end{thebibliography}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That worked fine. Thanks! But it leads to another question. I get this as an result: <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Kzj6SwD.png" width="860" height="818">; Now, I don't know how I get both chapters "Abbildungsverzeichnis" and "Literaturverzeichnis" into the header. Normally, the chapter title comes automatically to the header. But normally there is only one chapter per page. So what do how do I get both in the header? Thanks again!

Comment: @texnewbie Can you please ask that as a new question instead of a comment to this answer? Thanks!

Comment: @texnewbie: Use `\markboth{Abbildungsverzeichnis/Literaturverzeichnis}{Abbildungsverzeichnis/Literaturverzeichnis}`

Comment: @Herbert thanks! opened new question. That did it for me:

    `\cleardoublepage
    \markright{\listfigurename\ -- \bibname}
    \listoffigures
    \begingroup
    \let\cleardoublepage\relax
    \begin{thebibliography}{99}
    \bibitem[foo] bar baz
    \end{thebibliography}
    \endgroup`